# Creating Linked List and printing the elements?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I want to create a linked list of numbers from 1 to 1000 and print the numbers.
Im using the function `createList()` to create the list and `printList()` to print the elements.
But the following code is crashing. 
Can anybody please rectify. I'm new to linked list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
int data;
struct node* link;
};

struct node* head;

void deleteNode()
{

}

void createList()
{
    int i;
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head = temp;
    struct node* temp1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        temp->data = i+1;
        temp->link = temp1;
        temp1->link = temp++;
        temp1++;
    }
}

void printList()
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    } 
}

int main()
{
    head = NULL;
    createList();
    printList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you doing? Creating just two elements and putting 10 elements inside?

Comment: Refer and correct your create method .. http://www.c4learn.com/data-structure/c-program-to-create-singly-linked-list/

Comment: `But the following code is crashing` - a debugger can tell you exactly what line of code is crashing, that's useful information for someone to help you, or for you to help yourself. What are you expecting `temp++` and `temp1++` to do exactly?

Comment: at printList `struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` --> `struct node* temp;` don't need `malloc`

Comment: Can anybody tell me where im going wrong ?

Comment: at createList , There is a need to ensure every node of the loop.

Comment: Im sorry cant get you

Comment: case of 1～10  : 10 nodes is needed,  Do you know?

Answer (score 3):

```
void createList(){
    int i, size = 10;
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head = temp;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        temp->data = i+1;
        temp->link = i < size - 1 ? malloc(sizeof(struct node)) : NULL;
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}
```

---

```
void createList(){
    int i, size = 10;
    struct node* temp = malloc(size*sizeof(struct node));
    head = temp;

    if(temp){
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            temp->data = i+1;
            temp->link = temp + 1;
            ++temp;
        }
        temp[-1].link = NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void createList()
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp, *loc_head;
    loc_head = head;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        struct node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newnode->data = i+1;
        newnode->link = NULL;
        if(head == NULL) {
            head=newnode;
            loc_head = newnode;
        }
        else {
            head->link = newnode;
            head = newnode;
        }
    }
    head = loc_head;
}
```

[don't typecast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score -1):

Given an array of elements, create a linked list from the array (one new node per
element, using the function that adds nodes to the end of a list).

Comment: So, what's the question? Nobody's doing your assignment, if you don't show some effort first.